# download excel from the weblink as a DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x

I want to download the excelsheet from a link as a Dataframe.

```
    dls = "https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/-/media/boe/files/markets/asset-purchase-facility/gilt-purchases-in-nominal-terms.xls"
    xls = pd.read_excel(dls, 'APF Gilt purchases by nominal ')
```

I receive the following error:

```
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Is it an internal error, i.e. the link is working but the issue is on my end, or is the request erroneous?